# How to set value from controller to Input Box using "this" operator

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-controller

I am newbie to angular js. I got the data successfully from php but calling it from the controller, it's not working? I don't get any errors, my syntax is just wrong.
For eg: Suppose, A in entered in input box then On click event, B should be displayed in another text box.
If P is entered, then On click event, Q should be displayed and so on.

I am adding the text box using dynamically added rows. On each Click, data should be displayed.

HTML:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="bot in bottles">
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="bot.b_code" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" ng-click="accept1()" ng-model="bot.Pre_req"  /></td>
  </tr>
         <td><a href ng-click="remove_bottle(bottle)">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><a href ng-click="add_bottle()">Add</a></td></tr>
```

Controller:

```
   $scope.accept1=function(){
                  $http.get("machin.php", {params:{"W_id": this.bot.b_code}})
                     .success(function(response){
                        this.bot.Pre_req=response;
            }); 
    };
```

machin.php

```
if($W_id=='A')
 echo 'B'
else($W_id==P)
echo 'Q'
```

I unable to find the solution.Please do suggest.Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using `controller as` syntax?, or `$scope` ?

Comment: Not as a syntax. I just need to use "this" operator but I am unable to use it.

Comment: to use `this`, you need to implement `controller as` syntax, else go with `$scope`

Comment: How to use it controller as syntax. I had no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding bot to `$scope` instead of `this`

```
$scope.accept1=function(){
    $scope.bot = {};
    $http.get("machin.php", {params:{"W_id": this.bot.b_code}})
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.bot.Pre_req=response;
    }); 
};
```

In this case `this` would refer not even to scope of `accept1` function but to scope of anonymous function in success callback, so that's why it won't work as is. You can confirm this by trying to `console.log(this.bot)` in the end of `accept1` function. It will be `undefined`

Comment: I tried,but error displayed "Cannot set property 'Pre_req' of undefined"

Comment: I updated an answer. Try it now. Basically you can't set property of bot object because it doesn't exist, so you have to define that first, and set it's property later. You can also place `$scope.bot = {};` outside of `accept1` if you don't want to reset it every time function is called

Answer (score 0):

Since you use `$scope` way to implement things, So I suggest to completely remove `this` from your controller code, since it doesn't attach anything on view.

and, make below changes :

**1**.Define both `ng-model objects` in your controller, like :

```
 $scope.bot = {b_code:'', Pre_req : ''};
```

**2**.Change your `function call` with correct binding to `$scope`, like :

```
$scope.accept1=function(){
        var scope = $scope;
        $http.get("machin.php", {params:{"W_id": scope.bot.b_code}})
            .success(function(response){
                scope.bot.Pre_req=response;
        }); 
    };
```

also, change `.success` to `.then`, as it is depreciated.

**3**.I think you also need to change the `ng-click` target to upper input., as you are changing the below input. Code should be like:

```
  <td><input type="text" ng-click="accept1()" ng-model="bot.b_code" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="bot.Pre_req"  /></td>
```

**Second Approach**:, If you want to use `this` keywaord then I suggest having a read for [this syntax.](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/). Basically you have an alias for your `controller` in both html and JS, and `this` represent the controller alias in JS. (so you get rid of `$scope`)

Comment: I tried as per code, but No Output, No error.I defined both models in controller.Eventhough, its not working.

Comment: do you get data here `this.bot.Pre_req=response; ?`, post your response ?

Comment: @sam007: your `ng-click` target should be the `above input box`, i updated it in answer too.

Comment: @sam007: do you get call to php api,? and since you passing data, could you try with `$http.post()` as well. like :  `$http.post("machin.php", data:{"W_id": scope.bot.b_code})`